# Getting data from RPLidar A1 package to Arduino using rosserial

Tags: arduino, ros-noetic, rplidar, rosserial-arduino, arduino#ros#raspberry

We have an Arduino Uno board connected to raspberry pi 4 in which the RPLidar A1 is connected. The problem is we are trying to subscribe from the /scan topic to get the data from each ranges from 0 to 360 but somehow we can't and it says on the error 'message larger than the buffer size'. Does it mean Arduino Uno can't handle the LaserScan data from /scan topic?

Answer (score 0):

That maybe the reason. To solve it, try to reduce the amount of data by adjusting FOV or use higher specification boards such as arduino mega.
Also, you already have Raspberry Pi 4, but why you try to use the arduino uno? Connect rplidar directly to Raspberry Pi 4, it will be more stable.